# How to disable Heads Up notifications on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

How to disable the new **HeadsUp notifications** on android L. My app basically works as a app blocker and must not allow access to the blacklisted apps. For eg. If call app is blocked then user must not be able to access caller app. But, whenever any incoming call is received, it shows heads up notification on any screen. Whenever any such app is accessed by clicking the headsup notification the app gets blocked but in call case call can be received/rejected. Can we block such notifications in android.

Comment: I think you can have a read notification permission of some sort, and cancel them as they arrive : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html